# Is "type" optional in Json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Product set",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "title": "Product",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "description": "The unique identifier for a product",
                "type": "number"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "price": {
                "type": "number",
                "minimum": 0,
                "exclusiveMinimum": true
            },
            "tags": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "minItems": 1,
                "uniqueItems": true
            },
            "dimensions": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "length": {"type": "number"},
                    "width": {"type": "number"},
                    "height": {"type": "number"}
                },
                "required": ["length", "width", "height"]
            },
            "warehouseLocation": {
                "description": "Coordinates of the warehouse with the product",
                "$ref": "http://json-schema.org/geo"
            }
        },
        "required": ["id", "name", "price"]
    }
}
```

In the above Json schema "dimensions"is of "type": "object" , is type optional , if "type" is not specified should i assume it to be object. Could not find anything in specs related to optional elements.

Answer (score 2):

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-03#section-5.1

```
If the property is not defined or is not in this list, then any
type of value is acceptable.
```

type is optional, ANY value is acceptable if type is omitted.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is **not** optional. As you can see in the meta-schema below, the property "type" has no default value:

http://json-schema.org/schema

Also in my JSON Schema library [NJsonSchema](https://github.com/rsuter/NJsonSchema) I set the type to `None` instead of `Object`. Check out the `TypeRaw` property:

https://github.com/rsuter/NJsonSchema/blob/master/NJsonSchema/JsonSchema4.Serialization.cs

When the default value is set to `Object` a lot more tests from the JSON Schema test suite fail. Maybe you can find a definite answer in this JSON Schema test suite:

https://github.com/json-schema/JSON-Schema-Test-Suite

Comment: thank you for the answer.But you can see in the sample when "$ref" is present there is not "type" .                                                                                           "warehouseLocation": {
                "description": "Coordinates of the warehouse with the product",
                "$ref": "http://json-schema.org/geo"
            }

Comment: You are right.. I also think the meta schema is incorrect, the required declaration is comletely missing... I also found some other mistakes while implementing my lib... Why not start a discussion on the github json schema repo? (and link here?